# pass environment variables to services started with systemctl

Tags: systemd

I have a nodeJS service built using NodeJs. This service requires some environment variables to be passed to it. Moreover, I created a systemd unit file to start it from systemctl. For some weird reasons, the service, when started with systemctl, does not read the environment variables. For instance, one environment variable is the HOST, which contains the IP to which the sails app will be binded. However, if I start the service with **sails lift** or **node app.js**, it does read the environment variables.
Here is the unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=project

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /mnt/project/app.js
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried everything. I added the environment variables to /etc/environment and pointed the unit file to it, I also added them to the unit file, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 11):

This happens because a unit in systemd is encapsulated from rest of the system. Have you tried setting it directly in the unit file like this?

```
[Service]
Environment="FOO=foo" 'BAR=bar'
```

The variables FOO and BAR are then available in your unit. For example if this is my ExecuteStart:

> ExecStart=/bin/echo $FOO ${FOO} ${BAR}

With the `Environment` option from above this would result in the following output:

> foo foo bar

An alternative would be doing it via a environment config file. For this you can read the fedora dokumentation:

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Systemd#EnvironmentFiles_and_support_for_.2Fetc.2Fsysconfig_files

This link contains some useful examples with docker:

https://www.flatcar.org/docs/latest/setup/systemd/environment-variables/

Comment: Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue with `puma` not loading `.env` file values at all (on a ruby on rails web app)...

All i had to do was to define the values in the `puma.service` file using `Environment` for example:

`sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/puma.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/rails_current_server

Environment="RAILS_ENV=production"
Environment="SERVER_TYPE=111"

ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'bundle exec puma -C /home/ubuntu/rails_current_server/config/puma.rb'
Restart=always
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Another alternative will be hardcoding the values of the env vars right in the `ExecStart` something like this: `ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'RAILS_ENV=production SERVER_TYPE=111  bundle exec puma -C /home/ubuntu/rails_current_server/config/puma.rb'`